# How to look stored value in CoreData?

Tags: iphone

I am new on iphone development and I have problem with CoreData. I hardly made to sore value in CoreData but How can I look those value like in MySql WorkBench you can see the tables ad also values.In CoreData am I have chance like that?

Comment: Looks like Meko wants to open the sql store by the persistentStoreCoordinator using an external tool like MySql WorkBench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Core Data Editor](http://christian-kienle.de/CoreDataEditor/)

Answer (score 1):

Standalone app called Lita.

http://www.dehats.com/drupal/?q=node/58

It's free, quick and pretty useful for quick editing and viewing.
** Note it's an Adobe Air app.

Find your app database at
/Users/[USERNAME]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[VERSION]/Applications/[UUID]/Documents/[DBNAME].sqlite

Answer (score 0):

If you use Firefox then the [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5817) add-on is a good useful tool for viewing your tables, rows, etc.